# CodeRush Tricks of the Trade

Tags: .net, visual-studio, coderush

I was using [CodeRush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeRush) quite while ago and now I'm planning to use it again. I've installed the trial but I forgot all the cool features except <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> (drop a marker). And when you don't know some cool tricks it's really like burning money (since it's not cheap for personal use).

What do you like about it? What are your best features?

My best feature is marker:
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> (and use escape to go back)

**Currently What I like most**

- <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> / <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd>, etc. templates to create properties.
- <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> to create constructors.
- Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate between references to identifiers.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to find references in new cool window.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> for recent files.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> for jumping to any function /  class.
- <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> / <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> for "for loops".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recently installed the Xpress version and went on a similar hunt. [This cheat-sheet](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/markmiller/archive/2008/11/24/shortcuts-and-templates-quick-start-sheets-for-coderush.aspx) is what I found so far. The XPress version is pretty gimped BTW so I'm trying to get funding for a license.

Comment: keep posting if you got other good resources or tips, just for the records there are bunch of videos in here as well : http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/Training.xml

Answer (score 9):

I use these a lot:

- `/` will comment or uncomment highlighted blocks of code.
- `b` will wrap a highlighted selection in braces.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> will wrap a selection into a region.
- `tc` will generate a try/catch block.
- `mbs` will write a `MessageBox.Show("");` and drop the cursor in the quotes.
- `cws` will do the same but with `Console.Writeline`.
- `m` will create a method block (ms would do a method block that returns type string).
- `.` will make a comment block.

Comment: Didn't know commenting stuff, very cool.

Comment: If you go to DevExpress/Options/Editor/Templates you can see the whole list.  I make myself a cheat sheet of like 5 to learn every week or two.

Comment: I would really prefer if they did not have the mbs shortcut. The only reason you would really want that is for debugging which means it will be used and abused by people when there are a million better options available - unit testing, logging, or even Debug.WriteLine("")

Comment: Why / does not work? I have selected text, Shift + '/' - whole text in selection overwritten with '/'

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>NumPad+Plus</kbd> widens the scope of your selection one level.

Try it. It's sublime  :)

Comment: NumPad + Plus? what does it mean?

Comment: It means the plus key on the number pad, as opposed to the one in the main part of the keyboard (typically over the = on U.S. keyboards).

Comment: Ctrl-W also widens the selection scope. Shift-Ctrl-W narrows it.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>F2</kbd> - Rename

Strictly this is a RefactorPro shortcut as the Rename functionality is for RefactorPro. (However since RefactorPro is included in the Price of CodeRush that should not be an issue)

It is also, I think, Disabled by default.

You should be able to use the `DevExpress\Options...\IDE\Shortcuts` screen to search for <kbd>F2</kbd> and re-enable it.

Very natural to rename Vars and Methods using <kbd>F2</kbd> when you're already used to <kbd>F2</kbd> functionality for Files and Folders in Explorer.

Comment: that's sound good only problem is that my F2 is binded to "go to definition" :) But sounds like a good idea to give rename a shortcut.

Comment: A standard windows rename button!  You madam/sir rock.

Answer (score 6):

**Search for Type**

QuickNav (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) can be a bit excessive at times....

If you know you're looking for a Type, bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to **QuickNav** using additional params of "**AllTypes,, AllVisibilities, CurrentSolution**" (without quotes)

This will allow you to search for only Types in the current solution

These params can be tweaked to your liking. See http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/66380/225556.aspx#225556 for details

Comment: +1 Nice one. FWIW Ctrl-T normally swaps the char to the left of the caret with the one to the right (i.e., A|B becomes B|A). See http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx (So I usedl Alt-1 based on your other tip).

Answer (score 4):

rt / rf = For Return True and False

Answer (score 3):

**Search for Member**

QuickNav (**Ctrl+Shift+Q**) can be a bit excessive at times....

If you know you're looking for a Method, bind **Ctrl+M** to **QuickNav** using additionial params of "**AllTypes, AllMembers, AllVisibilities, CurrentFile**" (without quotes)

This will allow you to search for only Members in the current file.

These params can be tweaked to your liking. See http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/66380/225556.aspx#225556 for details

Comment: Did I ever tell that I love you Rory?

I set mine to Ctrl+Shift+M but this is great

Comment: Awesome. Careful with Ctrl-M as its the first part of a chord that covers a slew of code collapse stuff in Edit Advanced. Suggest a summary post of your custom hotkeys here or on your blog in order of how useful you think they are to the wider populace. See also http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple CodeRush Template for generating guard clauses.

Type **inx** <kbd>space</kbd> within a method, whilst you have a variable reference on the clipboard and you'll get...

```
If [VariableName] Is nothing Then
    return 
End If
```

or

```
if ([VariableName] == null)
{
    return;
}
```

... depending on the language you're currently operating in.

This Template is often referred to within [DevExpress Webinars](http://devexpress.com/Support/Webinars/series-details.xml?series=CodeRush%20Feature%20Workshop) as **If Not Null** or **If Null Exit**

Comment: For methods (not properties) there is the "Add Contract" refactoring for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [old post on the DevExpress Coderush Forum](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/57572.aspx):

In it is a setting suggestion by Mark Miller to enhance the default "Embed in Parenthesis" feature of CodeRush.

Once in place ... highlight some text and hit '('. your selection will be wrapped in Parenthesis and more importantly your caret will be on the left of the selection.
(Similar applies to the Right Parenthesis)

Ideal for VB.Net users to use alongside CInt, CStr etc

Answer (score 1):

Inside VS.NET

Press "Ctrl + Shift + Alt + O" will list all the DX Options (and putting shortcuts in the search box will bring you to the keyboard bindings)

Answer (score 1):

[CR_MetricShader](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/CR_MetricShader): is a free open source plugin for CodeRush or CodeRush Xpress which will allow you to see visually when your method's complexity is getting out of hand.

It alters the background color of your method to indicated severity with respect to your chosen Metric.

Works with the built in metrics of CodeRush (and the hidden ones in CodeRush Xpress) aswell as being compatible with any you might choose to create yourself.

Comment: I had a feeling your name would pop up again soon ;)