# Visual Studio 2010 shortcut to select word / expression / line / section / method?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

There is a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to select the entire word at the current cursor position.

Is there a similar shortcut that keeps expanding the selected region every time I apply it?

I mean, is there a shortcut which

- selects the word when applied once (same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>) and
- selects the entire line when applied twice in a row and
- selects the entire block when applied three times etc.,

i.e. keeps expanding the selected region step by step?

I remember seeing such a shortcut, but I don't remember whether it was for Visual Studio or some other editor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Solution for CodeRush**

Finally, I figured it out: the shortcut is the <kbd>numpad-plus</kbd> key after installing CodeRush Express for Visual Studio.

<sub>Source: Stack Overflow → CodeRush Tricks of the Trade → [Answer by moobaa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350383/coderush-tricks-of-the-trade/1162919#1162919)</sub>

**Solution for ReSharper**

Or if you use Resharper, it's the extend/shrink selection feature accessible via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

<sub>Source: Jetbrains.com → [extend/shrink documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#ExtendShrink_Selection)</sub>

Comment: Resharper selection only works for C#/VB, does not work for C++, same as built-in Ctrl+W

Answer (score 7):

Out of the box ReSharper uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to extend the selection.  Check the main menu under *ReSharper | Edit | Extend Selection*

It's not quite what you're looking for as it does Word, then block where block keeps getting bigger (e.g. method, class, etc).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to select a `line` or `lines` you can use the combination of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>U</kbd>.  This combination also works for `uncommenting` a complete line or lines(and also for indentation). This combination looks somewhat strange to work with, but it will get habituated very soon :)

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to cut an entire line. Similarly, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy an entire line. 
As long as you don't have anything selected, these commands will work on the entire line.

Answer (score 6):

My ReSharper keyboard shortcut was not set up to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.

The name for the command is `ReSharper.Resharper_ExtendSelection`.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this "Triple Click" VS2010 add-on last time I searched through the add-on gallery.
It's not quite what you're looking for (ie. it's not a hotkey and it won't select a block), but at least it will make it so that triple-clicking will select a whole line.  If you're extra-adventurous, it comes with source.. so you could potentially extend the functionality and/or make it a hotkey yourself.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/2bbdc70c-32f7-4b69-8cff-d8190cae0cc7

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the Text Selection section of this document.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx#editors

Answer (score 0):

Write a macro (or record one):

```
Sub SelectLine()
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine()
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine(vsStartOfLineOptions.vsStartOfLineOptionsFirstColumn)
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine(True)
End Sub
```

Then bind it to whatever key you want in tools->options->environment->keyboard.

The only problem with this is it doesn't save the position of the cursor, which is mildly annoying.