# CodeRush from DevExpress

Tags: coderush

if I may, I just would like to use this site to place some tips on using CodeRush from DevExpress...It may help some one. Thanks

from the VS IDE  Menu > DevExpress > Tool windows > Coderush
click any where in your code then you will get the possible keys menu to press depending where in code you are.

eg. click control+W inside any scope and the whole scope is selected.

sample:
to collapse getter to a single line (i used to do few clicks...no more)
i do click inside getter and click control+W then right click selection > Refactor! > collapse Getter. (next time you can click on the three dots at button of your selection)

have some usefull tips, lets collect them here. good coding.

Comment: CodeRush Tricks of the Trade -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350383/coderush-tricks-of-the-trade